# Switch with methods without constants

Tags: c#, .net, switch-statement, system.reflection

I want to accomplish this task is there any `method` in `C#`. give me syntax please.

```
switch(methods)
{
   case method1:
   //do method2
   case method3:
   // do method4
   case method5:
   // do method6
}
```

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you mean. Currently your question is very unclear.

Comment: What are you referring to ? Do you need syntax to use `Switch` which you already have in your question, or do you need examples on how to implement it ? Please refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This task could be accomplished using a specific variable like

```
method 1(){
//something
String id=1;
}
method 2(){
//something
String id=2;
}
```

Now use switch with id like

```
switch(id)
{
case 1:
//do something
case 2:
//do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that if you know the Class name and the method name actually. See below

```
Type magicType = Type.GetType("MagicClass");
MethodInfo magicMethod = magicType.GetMethod("ItsMagic");
        object magicValue = magicMethod.Invoke();
```

Check the below URL
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx